# cakephp translate query to cakephp model query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model

I have 2 models Scale and Step, where model Scale has many Step.
The db tables are:

```
scale : id | name | s1 | s2 | s3 | s4 | s5 | s6 | s7
step : id | val
```

I want to write the following query in cakephp structure...

```
select s.id, s1.val as v1, s2.val as v2, s3.val as v3, s4.val as v4, s5.val as v5, s6.val as v6, s7.val as v7
from scale s
join step s1 on s.s1 = s1.id
join step s2 on s.s2 = s2.id
join step s3 on s.s3 = s3.id
join step s4 on s.s4 = s4.id
join step s5 on s.s5 = s5.id
join step s6 on s.s6 = s6.id
join step s7 on s.s7 = s7.id
```

Can you please help me with the syntax??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->find('all', array(

        'fields' => array('s1.val', 's2.val'),
        'joins' => array(array(
            'table' => 'step',
            'alias' => 's1',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' =>array('Scale.s1 = s1.id')
            ),array(
            'table' => 'step',
            'alias' => 's2',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' =>array('Scale.s2 = s2.id')
            ),
        ),
        'conditions' => array('Scale.id = '.$id.'')
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you maybe change your database structure. Rather than having Step bound to s1, s2, s3...etc in Scale, which has a few disadvantages, one of which is that it restricts you to only 7 steps per Scale, and isn't really a good relational database model, I would suggest that you create a third table, called something like ScaleSteps, and has three columns:

```
id | ScaleId | StepId
```

Imagine you had a Scale entry with an id of 7, and that Scale had Step entries 1, 2, and 3 associated with it, the resultant table would look like this:

```
id | ScaleId | StepId
1  | 7       | 1
1  | 7       | 2
1  | 7       | 3
```

Then setup your CakePHP model relationships using: hasOne, belongsTo...etc, for example:

```
class Scale extends Model {
var $name = "Scale";
var $hasMany = "ScaleStep"; 
}

class ScaleStep extends Model {
var $name = "ScaleStep";
var $belongsTo = "Step";    
}
```

Comment: Thnk you for your answer. I want the scale actually to be restricted to only seven Steps thats why I designed it this way. I actually figured it out ...

Comment: No problem. I think I got belongsTo and hasOne mixed up in my answer anyway :) glad you solved it.